# IntegrityError when submit

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I am creating this app, where I want to be able to report a film to the admins database. At the moment I can go to a movie, then click report, and then be sent to the report_form template. But when I click the report button on this template, I only get this, and there is no reaction in the database: 
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: board_report.reporter_id

Does anybody have a solution for this?

**report_form.html**

```
{% extends "board/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load materializecss %}
{% block content %}
<div class="valign-wrapper row login-box">
    <div class="col card hoverable s10 pull-s1 m6 pull-m3 l8 pull-l2">
        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="card-content">
                <span class="card-title">Jusity why you want to report this film?</span>
                <div class="row">
                    {{ form|materializecss }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action right-align">
                <input type="reset" id="reset" class="btn-flat grey-text waves-effect">
                <input type="submit" class="btn green waves-effect waves-light" value="Report">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**models.py**

```
class Report(models.Model):
    reason = models.TextField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Reporter")
    reports = models.ForeignKey(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return f"{self.reports.title} reported by {self.reporter.username}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return reverse("film-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
class FilmReport(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Report
    fields = ["reason"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.films_view, name="board-home"),
    path("film/add", FilmAddView.as_view(), name="film-add"),
    path("film/<int:pk>/", FilmDetailView.as_view(), name="film-detail"),
    path("film/<int:pk>/report", FilmReport.as_view(), name="film-report"),
]
```

Comment: It means you did not add a value for `reporter` (and neither for `film`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you did not add a value for `reporter` (and neither for `reports`), so the database rejects the creation.

You can set the `reporter` and `reports` (to the `pk` in the URL) by overriding the `form_valid` method:

```
class FilmReportView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Report
    fields = ['reason']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.reporter = self.request.user
        form.instance.reports_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Implementing a `__str__` for a view is not done often. Furthermore a view has no title, hence `self.title` will not work.

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `View` suffix, so you should
>   consider renaming the view class to `FilmReportView`, instead of <s>`FilmReport`</s>.

Comment: I implementet your changes, and the error got away. Now I get this: 
"The view board.views.FilmReportView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."

Comment: @Jonas: sorry forgot the `return`. But likely the record is already in the database, it only did not redirect to the success url.

Comment: Just a quick question. When I report the movie, I get redirected to the next movie in the database. Why is that?

Comment: @Jonas: since you did not define a `success_url` in the view, it will redirect to the `get_absolute_url` of the object you created (here a `Report`). Likely that contains this url (which is a bit "odd"). For more information see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url